# show attirbute value as checkbox and get qty for each checkbox value

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, extensions, product-attribute

I am working on a magento project in which i want to set a product attribute value which will be displayed to customer as checkbox and also i want to get quantities for each checkbox value. if a customer selects two or more checkbox value and give quantities to those values i want to add them to cart and order. In cart and order it should display as 3 products(i mean same product but with different attribute value and qty).

I am a beginner for magento so please suggest me if there is there any magento extension available. Also i would like to get some help or idea on achieving this. Any help will be much appreciated.

If anyone need more information i will add it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the customer choose goes to the cart (and later to the order) you should not use product attributes but the product **custom option** instead.

This hint should guide you to the solution...